# LightDM configuration files

Tags: xubuntu, lightdm

I have an XUbuntu installation that uses LightDM that for some reason unkown to me went gabooey yesterday - black screen with just the mouse pointer on booting. (TTY's still working.)

After much reading I've reinstalled LightDM and now I get to the XUbuntu splash screen but no further.

/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log reports:

```
DEBUG: Seat: Failed to find session configuration xubuntu
```

and

```
DEBUG: Seat: Failed to find session configuration lightdm-gtk-greeter-ubuntu
```

Can someone tell me exactly what files LightDM is looking for and where it is looking for them?

There are .conf files with those names in /etc/lightdm, I've also tried copying them to other folders I've seen mentioned in posts.  I've also tried adding specific xsessions-directory and xgreeters-directory options to lightdm.conf but nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions, much appreciated.

Suds

Comment: I have lightdm.conf and users.conf in /etc/lightdm, as well as a subfolder lightdm.conf.d. In lightdm.conf.d, I have five more .conf files.

Comment: @Jos - thanks for the info, I had the same files, but still no idea where lightdm was looking for the ones that failed.  I gave up and re-installed.